# this.handleClick.bind(this) in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick, components

I want to create a pagination using a function component in React. My problem is that I can't use `this.handleClick.bind(this)` using this kind of structure. Is it possibile to use the pagination as well in other ways still using a function component? The code now is

```
import React from "react";

const Pagination = (props) => {
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // I can't use it
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(props.nameList.length / props.todosPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map((number) => {
    return (
      <li key={number} id={number} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {number}
      </li>
    );
  });
  return <ul id="page-numbers">{renderPageNumbers}</ul>;
};

export default Pagination;
```

Answer (score 2):

In functional component, you just have to define and use method directly without binding to context

```
import React from "react";

const Pagination = (props) => {
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log('ok')
  }
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(props.nameList.length / props.todosPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map((number) => {
    return (
      <li key={number} id={number} onClick={handleClick}>
        {number}
      </li>
    );
  });
  return <ul id="page-numbers">{renderPageNumbers}</ul>;
};

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: Yes, but, in this way the pagination it's not working. If I use this syntax this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);  in a class component and then i call onClick={this.handleClick} it changes page. So, what's the difference at this point?

Comment: @End.Game could you add more code, could be the place that use Pagination. Moreover, do you define `handleClick` at a different part?

Answer (score 0):

When you’re passing onClick handler you’re changing context from your component to a button element, meaning when your handler will be invoked this will refer to a button which in turn doesn’t have `.setState` method you will try to call. In order to fix it you basically have two options:

1. Explicitly bind this inside method to your component
2. Use class fields creating methods with arrow function:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Hello World'
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      name: ' Welcome to React'
    });
  };

  render() { /* As usual */  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Arrow function does not have concept of this and this inside arrow function always refers to outer context at declaration time, which will always be your component (exactly what you need).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we have this.handle on both side is because this.handle.bind(this) it creates a new function hence we need to assign new function reference back to this.handle

For reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind